# Object creation impossible in scala

Tags: scala, jnetpcap

I have the following error while executing the code below.

```
Object creation impossible, since member nextPacket(PcapPacket,T):void
  in org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler is not defined.
```

How can it be solved ?

```
while (true) {
  val jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler[String] {
    def nextPacket(packet: PcapPacket, user: String) {
      val data = new KeyedMessage[String, PcapPacket](topic.toString, packet)
      println(data)
      producer.send(data)
    }
  }
  pcap.loop(50, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap works!")
}
```

Comment: By defining `nextPacket(PcapPacket,T):void` in `org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler`, according to the error message.

Comment: @ChrisMartin look at the code.

Comment: I think it is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21247287/1804599) but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Where should I define it?

Comment: I guess the compiler and I were wrong, as it seems you already have. Can you make the code example more complete (an entire file that ought to compile, and specify the dependency and scala version)?

Comment: https://github.com/swe0523/producer/blob/master/producer.scala  - Link to code

Comment: What version of Scala compiler are you using, it works fine for me with Scala 2.10.4? Also what version of the libraries are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Following code seems to work fine with `scala-2.10.4` and  `jnetpcap-1.3.0`, meaning that I do not see any such compile time error as reported in the question:

```
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket

object JPCapExample {

  class KeyedMessage[K, V](k: K, v: V) {
    override def toString() = s"$k -> $v"
  }

  class Producer[K, V] {
    def send(data: KeyedMessage[K, V]) = {}
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val producer = new Producer[String, PcapPacket]
    val topic = "SomeTopic"
    val jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler[String] {
      def nextPacket(packet: PcapPacket, user: String) {
        val data = new KeyedMessage[String, PcapPacket](topic.toString, packet)
        println(data)
        producer.send(data)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Which version of jnetpcap and Scala were used?

Comment: And how does this answer the question asked above? Are you sure the problem is due to the incorrect `jnetpcap` version?

Comment: No.. I don't think its version problem.

Comment: @NorbertRadyk: Definitely not sure. However, I don't see any compilation error.