# Override Java method with arg Class<?> in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to subclass a class (Y) from an external library that can not be changed. It has a method as such:

```
protected Object doSomething(Class<?> clazz)
```

Now in my Scala class (X) I am extending this class and trying to override the method.

```
override protected def doSomething(clazz: Class[_ <: Object]): AnyRef
```

However this results in 'Method doSomething overrides nothing'. Changing the code to:

```
override protected def doSomething(clazz: Class[_]): AnyRef
```

Stops this error but now when the class is compiled it results in the following error:

```
class X needs to be abstract, since method doSomething in class Y of type (x$1: Class[_ <: Object])Object is not defined 
(Note that Class[_ <: T] does not match Class[_]: their type parameters differ)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Scala Version: 2.12.1, Java Version 8.

Comment: Please tell us jdk and scala versions

Comment: Have you tried to just do `override def doSomething[T](clazz: Class[T]): AnyRef`?

Comment: `override def doSomething(clazz: Class[_]): AnyRef = ???` compiles fine with Scala 2.11.8 and JDK 8u91

Comment: @marstran that results in the "overrides nothing" error again.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the second error. I placed `public class Base { protected Object doSomething(Class<?> clazz) { ... } }` in a Java file, compiled it, then put it on the REPL classpath. Then I typed `class Sub extends Base { override def doSomething(clazz: Class[_]): AnyRef = ??? }`, and it compiled fine. Same Scala/Java versions.

Comment: Is the external library that you use publicly available?

Comment: I also can not reproduce the second error.

Comment: @mixel The library is Spring 4.2, the class (Y) is the GsonHttpMessageConverter that in turn extends from AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<Object> which is where the original "doSomething" method is defined. The method that I am trying to overwrite is readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage). The way I have fixed this so far is to extend from AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter instead of GsonHttpMessageConverter, but this is not ideal really.

Comment: Could you add full example reproducing your issue with `build.sbt` containing Spring dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Overriding Generic Java Methods II](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440176/scala-overriding-generic-java-methods-ii)

Comment: @RyanBurke Does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question you did not mention that `Object doSomething(Class<?> clazz)` method is the implementation of `abstract T doSomething(Class<? extends T> clazz)` method of abstract generic class.

So actually you have following Java classes (I renamed `doSomething` to `test` for brevity):

```
public abstract class AbstractJava<T> {
    protected abstract T test(Class<? extends T> c);
}

public class ConcreteJava extends AbstractJava<Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object test(Class<?> c) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you are trying to implement following Scala class:

```
class ConcreteScala extends ConcreteJava {
    override protected def test(c: Class[_]) = super.test(c)
}
```

But compilation fails because when you try to override `test()` Scala treats `ConcreteJava.test()` and `AbstractJava.test()` methods as if they have different signature.

I found the following workaround.

Create additional Java class that by overriding `test()` "renames" it to `renameTest()` and also provides ability to call super `ConcreteJava.test()` through `concreteTest()` method.

```
public abstract class RenameJava extends ConcreteJava {
    public Object concreteTest(Class<?> c) {
        return super.test(c);
    }

    abstract protected Object renameTest(Class<?> c);

    @Override
    protected Object test(Class<?> c) {
        return renameTest(c);
    }
}
```

Now in `ConcreteScala` class you can override `renameTest()` and you're still able to call super `ConcreteJava.test()` method using `concreteTest()` method.

```
class ConcreteScala extends RenameJava {
  override protected def renameTest(c: Class[_]) = {
    // custom logic
    concreteTest(c)
  }
}
```

In your specific "Spring" case it's implemented in the following way.

**RenameGsonHttpMessageConverter.java**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter;

import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class RenameGsonHttpMessageConverter extends GsonHttpMessageConverter {

    protected Object superReadInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws 
            IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return super.readInternal(clazz, inputMessage);
    }

    abstract protected Object renameReadInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws 
            IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException;

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return renameReadInternal(clazz, inputMessage);
    }
}
```

**CustomGsonHttpMessageConverter.scala**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage

class CustomGsonHttpMessageConverter extends RenameGsonHttpMessageConverter {
  override protected def renameReadInternal(clazz: Class[_], inputMessage: HttpInputMessage) = {
    // custom logic
    // or you may want to call
    superReadInternal(clazz, inputMessage)
  }
}
```

Also I made a bug report [SI-10155](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10155).